# Update cell in a database but not to delete the previous value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am implementing Bodybuilding Gym website in asp.net and C#.
I would like to enrol gym members for classes like e.g. Yoga, ABS.
I want to add them to the table Workout and column called Participants.
The table has 6 columns (ID, Date, Type, Description, Status, Participants).
Here's my code.

```
GridViewRow row = DataGrid1.SelectedRow;
string hour = row.Cells[1].Text;
string type = row.Cells[2].Text;
string participant = Session["New"].ToString() + ", ";

SqlConnection EnrolForConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
EnrolForConn.Open();
string EnrolForStatement = "update [Workout] set [Participants]=@Participants where Date = '" + hour + "' and Type = '" + type + "'";
SqlCommand EnrolForCommand = new SqlCommand(EnrolForStatement, EnrolForConn);
EnrolForCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Participants", participant);

int x = EnrolForCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (x == 0)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Error !!!');", true);
}
else
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('You have been enrolled for class !!!');", true);
}

EnrolForConn.Close();
```

When I add first participant, it works. But when I add second one (being logged in to another acount), it deletes the first one. I don't want to delete the previous participants.

Also, I would like to limit the number of participants e.g. max 10 (I am using comma to separate participants).

Any advice? ;)
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually updating `Participants` column with the value present in participant, thus only the last one will be persisted.

In order to have all the participants in the field, you have to write something like the following:

```
// get all the participants in a list
// e.g. IList<String> participantsList
participant = String.Join(", ", participantsList);
```

**Side notes:**

However, it is recommended to normalize your data and have a separate table for the participants. This way, you can have define a table for users/participants and only store a X relation between Event and Participant.

Not only that storage is saved, but future queries dealing with Events and Participants will be easier to write (no string splitting).

Also, try to use parameters for everything that can be parameterized:

```
string EnrolForStatement = "update [Workout] set [Participants]=@Participants where Date = @Hour and Type = @Type";
EnrolForCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hour", hour);
EnrolForCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", type);
```